# How to draw a path with borders?

Tags: android, android-canvas

[image: example path]

I want to draw a path similar to the image. It has two black borders and the inside is white instead of transparent. How to achieve it ? especially the joint position.

Comment: drawPath twice with different colors snd stroke width

Comment: if you tried it, you would find it not working. The joint will not have black lines.

Comment: ok, so you cannot do it with one Path, you have to draw two Path segments one overdrawing the other one

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get the desired result, you'll have to draw the path in parts.

You'll draw the parts twice, with two different `Paint` objects, differing only in Stroke-width and color. After drawing each part, the Path will be reset. The code-comments should explain the rest:

```
public class SView extends View {

    Path path;
    Paint paint, paintWhite;
    RectF rf, rf2, rf3;

    public SView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        path = new Path();

        // 'paint' has a wider stroke-width 
        // compared to 'paintWhite' and 
        // thus becomes the border paint
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        // 'paintWhite' colors the inner path
        paintWhite = new Paint();
        paintWhite.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintWhite.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintWhite.setStrokeWidth(12);
        paintWhite.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        // For this example, we'll draw three
        // arcs bound by the following RectF
        // objects
        rf = new RectF(200, 200, 500, 500);
        rf2 = new RectF(200, 200, 400, 500);
        rf3 = new RectF(100, 200, 400, 500);                    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {          

        // First arc bound by 'rf'
        path.arcTo(rf, 0, 180);

        // Draw 'path' using 'paint' 
        // and then, again using 'paintWhite'       
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paintWhite);

        // Reset 'path' so as to clear 
        // history
        path.reset();

        // Repeat with the rest of arcs
        path.arcTo(rf2, 180, 180);      
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paintWhite);      
        path.reset();           

        path.arcTo(rf3, 0, 180);            
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paintWhite);  

    }       
}
```

Output:

[image]

Note: The arc that overlaps is bound by `RectF rf3`, and is drawn last.

Since we are drawing the `white` portion along with the `borders`, you will not end up with the four way crossing. The parts will overlap in a `flyover` kind of fashion: in the order that they are drawn.

To boost performance (I suppose), you can check whether the next part of the path will intersect with any previous ones before resetting the path. If the next part does intersect, reset and draw the part with the two Paint objects. If it doesn't, just append the part to the Path and wait until the next intersection to draw it. You'll of course need to maintain a history of parts drawn (in the example above, history would contain the bounds: 'RectF' objects). However, I'm not a 100% sure if this is better than repeatedly resetting the path and then drawing the parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using two different Paint objects to draw the same path. The first Paint object will have the colour you want for the borders and a large stroke width. The second Paint will have a lesser stroke width with `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` set on it.

```
linePaint = new Paint();
linePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
linePaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
linePaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

clearPaint = new Paint();
clearPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
clearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
clearPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
clearPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
```

Then in your onDraw() method, draw the same path twice using the above two paints.

```
canvas.drawPath(path, linePaint);
canvas.drawPath(path, clearPaint);
```

This might not be very efficient in terms of performance, but it's the simplest way that I could think of.

EDIT: Havent't tested this thoroughly myself, so do let me know if there are any issues.

UPDATE: After testing this, I've found that the PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR will clear the entire pixel information present in the canvas' backing bitmap. So one will usually end up with something like this:

[image: Path filled with black]

The solution to fix this would be to create an off-screen canvas to draw the path on.

```
Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();
Bitmap backingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


canvas2.setBitmap(backingBitmap);
canvas2.drawPaint(clearPaint);
canvas2.drawPath(path, linePaint);
canvas2.drawPath(path, clearPaint);

canvas.drawBitmap(backingBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Using the above method, you get the following result:
[image: Correct borders]

The downside being, creating bitmaps may hinder performance if you are doing it every frame. The size of the Bitmap also affects performance adversely. So you'll want to create the off-screen canvas only when necessary and as long as you don't need to reset your path info, you can continue drawing onto the previously created backingBitmap.

Comment: Thank you for your illustration. I got your point, but another very lethal problem is the intersection of the line : I need to know which line is on the top. If you look carefully at my image you will find the intersection is different from yours.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did notice that while posting my answer, but I couldn't figure out how that can be achieved. I'll update my answer if I find a better solution that addresses that.